# Weird bug when compiling for release?

Tags: swift

This line in my code is where my app keeps crashing only upon the release build.

`self.setup.monthByInt = [1:"January", 2:"February", 3:"March", 4:"April", 5:"May", 6:"June", 7:"July", 8:"August", 9:"September", 10:"October", 11:"November", 12:"December"]`

```
func updateMonthArrayForCircle(){
    self.setup.monthByYear = ["January":0, "February":0, "March":0, "April":0, "May":0, "June":0, "July":0, "August":0, "September":0, "October":0, "November":0, "December":0]
    self.setup.monthByInt = [1:"January", 2:"February", 3:"March", 4:"April", 5:"May", 6:"June", 7:"July", 8:"August", 9:"September", 10:"October", 11:"November", 12:"December"]
}
```

`self.setup` references a struct where I store the original array with the same value in a `[Int:String]` initialized object.

```
struct initialize {
    let largeFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 130)
    let smallFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 15, y: 25, width: 100, height: 100)
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var month: [String] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var monthByYear: [String:Int] = ["January":0, "February":0, "March":0, "April":0, "May":0, "June":0, "July":0, "August":0, "September":0, "October":0, "November":0, "December":0]
    var monthPure: [String] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    var monthByInt: [Int:String] = [1:"January", 2:"February", 3:"March", 4:"April", 5:"May", 6:"June", 7:"July", 8:"August", 9:"September", 10:"October", 11:"November", 12:"December"]
    var intByMonth: [String:Int] = ["January":1, "February":2, "March":3, "April":4, "May":5, "June":6, "July":7, "August":8, "September":9, "October":10, "November":11, "December":12]
    var monthIndex: Int = 7
}
```

The code works fine in debug mode.

Error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the full stack trace.

Comment: @Timmy it's really large, but would the picture I just uploaded be of enough use?

Comment: My bad, I was referring to the stack trace found under the debug navigator. It is at the top left of Xcode under the stop button.

Comment: @Timmy my fault for not knowing, is that the right picture?

Comment: Can you provide to me the surrounding code that calls the `updateMonthArrayForCircle` function.

Comment: @Timmy updated with the surrounding code.

Comment: is `amareUserDone` being called in a completionHandler?

Comment: @Timmy Yes! I am uploading the picture in which it is

Comment: Disable whole module optimization if it's enabled. That caused similarly weird crashes for me before.

Comment: @Timmy If a user is detected it then fires a "checkup" to sync the data from the relevant friends profile to the current user's friends, keeping the data up to date.

Comment: Yea if you upload the picture off the completion handler I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Timmy I uploaded both, my internet was really slow, but I got it to upload finally

Comment: @Timmy it's really hard to explain what's going on, but I basically have a file called Existence that pulls all the usernames and finds the user's UID in which pulls their profile information and then updates the friend object of the relevant friend within the user's friends list. and the fires amareuserdone after each successful completion, but amareuserdone will not do anything until the count of completions has met the amount of amareuser's detected.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, check my answer.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys why did this work?! Is this safe to do? Or should I still look through my code, optimize it by hand, etc.. and find a solution that keeps `whole module optimization`

Comment: @NashEquilibrium if it fixed the crash you've uncovered a Swift optimizer bug. You should file a report at bugs.swift.org. It is safe to disable wmo. Try switching to single file optimization as a first measure. Your app might end up being a teeny bit larger, but you really shouldn't see any difference in performance. If you have a CI build, your build time will probably increase. I was able to fiddle with my code to work around the optimizer bug, but my bug was very different than yours so I don't have any advice unfortunately.

Comment: As a point supporting that it's fine to disable it. It wasn't available until Xcode 7/Swift 2 and it wasn't enabled by default until Xcode 8/Swift 3. See [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-whole-module-optimization/) for an explanation of what it is. And [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5167?filter=-2) is the big I encountered. You can see it was resolved pretty quickly.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys I forgot to mention this bug only occurs on the iPhone 5 that has their storage "almost full." I have tested it out on many devices. The iPhone 5 and 5c are the culprit and below (though I haven't tested on the 4 since i am deploying only onto ios 10)

Comment: That makes it sound like an arm7 (32-bit) vs arm64 (64-bit) issue. Though I can't begin to fathom why "almost full" disk space could manifest itself as an ARC issue.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys I have a clean iPhone 5, and it works very well, compared to the iPhone 5 in question with the almost full disk, the optimizer bug comes into play. It's definitely odd, I am going to file a bug with swift now, while doing so I am going to optimize and tweak my code to see if itll work at some point.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys I made a new variable within the struct called "_monthByInt" with the same value and I reset the variable in the function to the variable in question in stead and it seems to work now (with -wmo)! It's weird that simply reseting the variable to the value itself is causing the bug, but when assigned to a separate variable (stored within the struct only) with the same value it works?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the reason for your problem is because you are using escaping closures. The function returns before the completion handler is called.

Here is the solution:

```
sync(completionHandler: { [weak self] (success) -> Void in
    if success {
        self?.delegate?.amareUserDone()
    }
})
```

Comment: When I get back home I am going to look more into this. Thank you so so much!

Comment: I am adjusting all the related completion handlers towards this solution. It doesn't seem to work just yet. Is there something wrong with using `@escaping`? in my completion handlers.

Comment: Try passing in the weak instance of self through amareUserDone

Comment: like so? `self?.delegate?.amareUserDone(objectFriend: self?)`

Comment: Yea, and then use that self to set the monthByInt

Comment: the variable `monthByInt` is stored within the class, `HomeController` not `Friend` do I still have to go this route to setup monthByInt via Friend

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. I am almost positive the problem os with the closures, it's really late where I am right now but read up on escape closures

Comment: will do! Thanks a lot for your help tim!